# Adding sid to idtoken in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

According to documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#next-steps

The path for addding sid as optional claim is to add:

```
    "optionalClaims": {
    "idToken": [
        {
            "name": "sid",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": []
        }
```

Into the application manifest, i have done this and still no claim.

I have a custom policy running, and tried to find any hints there as well, but can't get sid to appear anywhere. No matter the optional claim i add, the token is the same.

We need to add sid for SSO between subdomains we have.

Answer (score 0):

The article you have referenced is for Azure AD, not B2C.

sid is not part of the [B2C schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema).

Are you federating with Azure AD?

If so, [map sid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider-1) to an extension claim.