# How to use SSO with MSAL.js and Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have a couple of Angular-applications which all use Azure AD B2C + msal.js where I want the users to be able to switch between the applications without having to login all over again.

I have been able to implement this by having the applications calling the loginRedirect()-function, since there is an active session on b2clogin.com they won't have to reenter any credentials. However I would prefer to use the ssoSilent()-function, to avoid the redirects, as specified in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso.

I've tried using loginHint with the users email, but nothing happens and this error message is displayed in the console:
`ERROR InteractionRequiredAuthError: interaction_required: AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'.`

I was also looking into the other option with session ID, but if I understand correctly this method isn't applicable to B2C ([Adding sid to idtoken in Azure B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75695445/adding-sid-to-idtoken-in-azure-b2c)).

Have anyone else been able to implement the ssoSilent()-function with Azure AD B2C and can help me with what I'm missing?